# menu sliding up instead of down

Tags: css, menu, slider

Hello i'm using this menu under capabilities check this web

http://www.dt-gaming.com

when you click on it i'd like to make it go up instead of going down does any one know how can i do that?

here is the code for the menu

```
<div id="capabilities">CAPABILITIES</div>
            <div id="bleft">
            <ul class="menu1">
           <li class="item1"><a href="#">TECH </a>
           <ul>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Web hosting</a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Internet Security and Penetration testing </a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">PCI/DSS compliance</a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Custom web sites for portfolios</a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Mobile apps </a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li class="item2"><a href="#">GRAPHIC </a>
            <ul>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Brands & Identity design </a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Creative web design </a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Graphic design </a></li>


            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item3"><a href="#">MARKETING </a>
        <ul>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Marketing strategy </a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Email marketing </a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Email template coding </a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Telemarketing </a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Graphic design  </a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">White-hat SEO</a></li>
                <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Google adwords optimization </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var menu_ul = $('.menu1 > li > ul'),
               menu_a  = $('.menu1 > li > a');

        menu_ul.hide();

        menu_a.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
                menu_a.removeClass('active');
                menu_ul.filter(':visible').slideUp('normal');
                $(this).addClass('active').next().stop(true,true).slideDown('normal');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideUp('normal');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

The CSS

```
#capabilities
    {
        color:#fff;
        font-family:myFirstFont;
        font-size:24px;
        float:right;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-right:20px;
    }
    .menu1 {
        float:right;
        margin-top:275px;
        text-decoration:none;
        list-style:none;
        font-size:24px;
        margin-right:-95px;;
        text-align:right;
        width: 240px;
        height: auto;
    }

    .menu1 > li > a {

        display: block;
        position: relative;
        font-family: "myFirstFont";
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration:none;


    }
    .menu1 ul li a {


        position: relative;
        font-family: "myFirstFont";
        font-size:18px;
        margin-left: -190px;
        color: #FC0;
        text-decoration:none;

    }
    .menu1 ul li:last-child a {
        list-style:none;
        color: #FC0;
    }
    .menu1 > li > a:hover, .menu > li > a.active {
        list-style:none;
        color: #fff;

    }
    .menu1 > li > a.active {
        list-style:none;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .menu1 > li > a:before {
        content: '◀';
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #fff;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 50%;
        margin: -.8em 0 0 17.8em;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The menu opens down because the element is "docked" at the top (be default). If you "dock" the element by its bottom specifically, then the element will grow up rather than down. You can do that by setting `bottom : 0; position: absolute;` on the `ul.menu1` element.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
#bleft {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.menu1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Remove:

```
.menu1 {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 95px;
    margin-top: 275px;
}
```